# "server closed the connection unexpectedly" in long running task after trying to save stuff to db

Tags: python, django, celery

I have django app and celery workers.

One celery task is quite huge and can run for over 15 minutes. When main calculations are done and I try to save results to db I get an error: `psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly`.

```
@celery_app.task
def task(param):
  Model1.objects.create(...)
  huge_calculations(param)  # may run for over 15 minutes
  Model2.objects.create(...)  # <- error here
```

Everything that I managed to google refers to the simple solution: "update everything", but I already did, have latest versions of every package in project and still have this error.

For short task (even same task w/ different params) everything works fine.

I've also tried to adjust db connection timeout, but no luck :/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [this?](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/829)

> I'm having the same issue. For now as a workaround had to create wrapper around
>   connection object with used methods to hook them. In cursor() method had to do a 
>   `SELECT 1` "ping" check and reconnect if needed to return a valid working cursor.